# as3 arraycollection

Tags: actionscript-3

I am doing an pure AS3 programming, and I have urge to work with something like ArrayList because I need an array of objects (which in this case, array class is no use).
However it seems there is no ArrayList class for me to import (Flex has but ...)
I also found an open-source project called as3-collection on internet, but what the hell??? cant find any link to download...

Comment: Exactly What feature are you looking for that Array/Vector/Dictionary does not have?

Comment: 'Cause normal array can't work with objects so I need an ArrayCollection to do such things...

Comment: arrays work with objects.  i'm not sure why you think otherwise.  read about the Array class in the documentation: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html .  if you're only storing Objects in your array you could/should use Vector.<Object>: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html

Comment: I think he really just want a cup of beer.... and if it's a "she" then something "else".. (:

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Arrays work just fine with objects, but if you want strict enforcement of datatypes, try the `Vector` class.

Comment: At contratio : see the reference on Adobe website!

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS4bebcd66a74275c3a0f5f19124318fc87b-7fff.html so upvoted!

Comment: Use Vectors for performance and type safety! see the topic here : 

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/618574 @Robusto is right!

Answer (score 1):

```
var yourArray:Array;
var yourObject:Object;

...

yourArray = [];

yourArray.push(yourObject);
```

Is it something like that? Maybe I don't understand the question...

Answer (score 1):

If you really need the methods of the ArrayList you could have a shot at creating your own implementation.

ArrayList is mainly a bunch of methods with an Array as the backend, it simplifies interaction with the Array but doesn't seem to do things that you wouldn't be able to do with an Array.

If you're looking for easier manipulation of data, create your own class with the necessary methods.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for [ArrayCollection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ArrayCollection.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2).

If you'd tell me what you want to do with your array of objects then I could give you a more concise direction to how and what to do. It shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Sorry but it's not I am looking for. As I mentioned, I am not using Flex framework so there is no mx.collections packet for me to import

Comment: Sorry, I thought you mean a Flex ActionScript3 project.. What functionality are you looking for? And, I conclude that you're using Flash only, right? Which version by the way?

Comment: Oh as I said, I need an array of objects, add object, retrieve object and such thing. And I am using Flash CS5

Comment: Then regular array should suffice. Declare it as var my_array:Array = [];

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Robusto:

```
var ObjectsLenght:uint=10;
var vectorOfObjects:Vector.<Object> = new Vector.<Object>();
for (var i:uint=0 ;i<ObjectsLenght;i++){
    var o:Object = new Object();
    vectorOfObjects.push(o);
};
for (var j:uint=0 ;j<ObjectsLenght;j++){
    trace("Object["+j+"] = " + vectorOfObjects[j]);
};
```

Try to be more Specific, if you use a class of your choice...

For example MyClass.as:

```
package  {
    public class MyClass {
        var id:String;
        public function MyClass(id:uint) {
            this.id = "instance_of MyClass_" + id.toString()
        }
        public function getID():String{
            return this.id;
        }
    }
}
```

You're now able to create a Vector with MyClass as this :

```
import MyClass;
var instancesLenght:uint=10;
var vectorOfMyClass:Vector.<MyClass> = new Vector.<MyClass>();
for (var n:uint=0 ;n<instancesLenght;n++){
    var instance:MyClass = new MyClass(n);
    vectorOfMyClass.push(instance);
};
for (var m:uint=0 ;m<ObjectsLenght;m++){
    trace("MyClass["+m+"] = " + vectorOfMyClass[m] + " (" + vectorOfMyClass[m].getID() + ")");
};
```

As long as a Class extends the Object class, and you want change dynamically some properties, just declare your Class as dynamic like this.

```
package  {
    public dynamic class MyClass {
        var id:String;
        public function MyClass(id:uint) {
            this.id = "instance_of MyClass_" + id.toString()
        }
        public function getID():String{
            return this.id;
        }
    }
}
```

and then you may do this :

```
import MyClass;
var instancesLenght:uint=10;
var vectorOfMyClass:Vector.<MyClass> = new Vector.<MyClass>();
for (var n:uint=0 ;n<instancesLenght;n++){
    var instance:MyClass = new MyClass(n);
    instance.nameOfInstance = "ins_" + n.toString();
    vectorOfMyClass.push(instance);
};
for (var m:uint=0 ;m<ObjectsLenght;m++){
    trace("MyClass["+m+"] = " + vectorOfMyClass[m] + " (" + vectorOfMyClass[m].getID() + ")" + "name = " + vectorOfMyClass[m].nameOfInstance);
};
```

In the first case, you'll get this output :

```
Object[0] = [object Object]
Object[1] = [object Object]
Object[2] = [object Object]
Object[3] = [object Object]
Object[4] = [object Object]
Object[5] = [object Object]
Object[6] = [object Object]
Object[7] = [object Object]
Object[8] = [object Object]
Object[9] = [object Object]
```

In the second case this one :

```
MyClass[0] = [object MyClass] (instance_of MyClass_0)name = ins_0
MyClass[1] = [object MyClass] (instance_of MyClass_1)name = ins_1
MyClass[2] = [object MyClass] (instance_of MyClass_2)name = ins_2
MyClass[3] = [object MyClass] (instance_of MyClass_3)name = ins_3
MyClass[4] = [object MyClass] (instance_of MyClass_4)name = ins_4
MyClass[5] = [object MyClass] (instance_of MyClass_5)name = ins_5
MyClass[6] = [object MyClass] (instance_of MyClass_6)name = ins_6
MyClass[7] = [object MyClass] (instance_of MyClass_7)name = ins_7
MyClass[8] = [object MyClass] (instance_of MyClass_8)name = ins_8
MyClass[9] = [object MyClass] (instance_of MyClass_9)name = ins_9
```

I hope this helps.